# Postgres keeps forgetting my data

Tags: postgresql, linux

I'm fairly new to Postgres, having spent years with MySQL/MariaDB.  I have a Postgres 14.9 database for development with two schemas in it.  When I lose power, both of the schemas still exist in the database, but the data for one of the schemas is gone. The log says:

```
[1199] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
[1199] LOG:  redo starts at 0/3094A290
[1199] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/3094A378: wanted 24, got 0
[1199] LOG:  redo done at 0/3094A340 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
[1050] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Since this is for development, losing that data isn't a big deal; I just keep importing a dump, but I'd like to know why this is happening and what I can to to prevent it, especially when I take this system to production.  I haven't changed any settings in Postgres or in the OS regarding disk cache.  I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 in a VM, and the host is Windows 10 on an SSD.

Also, is there a way I can recover the data without importing my dump?  I did some research which led me to try `pg_resetxlog` and `pg_resetwal`, but both said `command not found`.

Comment: Perhaps your VM is ignoring fsync to speed up IO? This is a complex durability issue that the database itself cannot fix: if *any* of the IO layers (guest OS, hypervisor, host OS, disk controller, SSD itself) does not perform fsync correctly, then data can be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I created my tables as `UNLOGGED`, and forgot to run my other file that sets them to `LOGGED`.  That seems to be expected behavior.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

> If specified, the table is created as an unlogged table. Data written
> to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log (see Chapter
> 30), which makes them considerably faster than ordinary tables.
> However, they are not crash-safe: an unlogged table is automatically
> truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown. The contents of an
> unlogged table are also not replicated to standby servers. Any indexes
> created on an unlogged table are automatically unlogged as well.
>
> If this is specified, any sequences created together with the unlogged
> table (for identity or serial columns) are also created as unlogged.